# lua sting.match need for only first detection

Tags: string, lua, pattern-matching

I am working on a bluray folder to detect the BDMV folder using io.open

when using for loop to find folders in NAS location i am using sting.find to get "BDMV" mentioned in to folder list. I am storing this value in a table.

The problem is when i run the code it will list out all the child directory and also add it in to table.

I want only the first instance of the folder like

```
1=Minions.2015.1080p.BluRay.AVC.TrueHD.7.1.Atmos-RARBG/BDMV
```

what i am getting is

list of all sub folders and files

```
1=Minions.2015.1080p.BluRay.AVC.TrueHD.7.1.Atmos-RARBG/BDMV
2=Minions.2015.1080p.BluRay.AVC.TrueHD.7.1.Atmos-RARBG/BDMV/AUXDATA
3=Minions.2015.1080p.BluRay.AVC.TrueHD.7.1.Atmos-    RARBG/BDMV/AUXDATA/sound.bdmv
4=Minions.2015.1080p.BluRay.AVC.TrueHD.7.1.Atmos-RARBG/BDMV/BACKUP
5=Minions.2015.1080p.BluRay.AVC.TrueHD.7.1.Atmos-RARBG/BDMV/BACKUP/BDJO
6=Minions.2015.1080p.BluRay.AVC.TrueHD.7.1.Atmos-    RARBG/BDMV/BACKUP/BDJO/00000.bdjo
7=Minions.2015.1080p.BluRay.AVC.TrueHD.7.1.Atmos-RARBG/BDMV/BACKUP/BDJO/00001.bdjo
8=Minions.2015.1080p.BluRay.AVC.TrueHD.7.1.Atmos-RARBG/BDMV/BACKUP/BDJO/00002.bdjo
```

And So on....................

This are around 1000+ file entries that i dont want.

I have tried the sting.match to match a pattern and detect only first instance and ignore the rest. So far No luck.

```
if string.find(t,"BDMV") then
    if string.match(t,"(.+/BDMV)") then

    Movies[#Movies+1] = t
else
   print("ignor")
end
```

Please let  me know if you need more detail.Thanks.

Comment: `if string.find(t,"BDMV$") then` might do the job

Answer (score 2):

```
local already_have = {}
local Movies = {}

-- Start of your loop
   -- local t = ...
   local name = string.match(t, "^.+/BDMV%f[%W]")  -- Thanks to Paul for advice
   if name and not already_have[name] then
      already_have[name] = true
      Movies[#Movies+1] = t
   end
-- end of loop
```

Comment: `^.+` makes no difference in this case, so can be removed. Also, you'll probably want to use frontier pattern after `BDMV`, otherwise it will also match on `/BDMVsomethingelse`. Or just check for `/BDMV$` and skip the `already_have` cache.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko - `^.+` can't be removed because prefix before `BDMV` is necessary to detect duplicates.  The main idea is to cut off suffix.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko - The idea about `/BDMV$` was already suggested by @Jakuje.

Comment: @ppperry - I know nothing about the context.  Only OP can answer this question.

Comment: "The idea about `/BDMV$` was already suggested by @Jakuje." -- yes, but without the slash it doesn't always do what's intended.

Comment: What does your code do? Why does it solve the OP's problem? That was what I was asking.

Comment: @ppperry - My code simply rejects duplicates.  This is what OP wants.